# What to do if a question is unanswered?

Tags: support, questions, answers, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I have asked a question and got only 3 views without any comment nor answer.

So I decided to ask a new question to clearify and made it a bit more generic so it might be also of use for others. However, I still did not get any answer.

Is this allowed or is there a better way?

Also I noticed that depending on the time a question is asked one gets many more views than at other times and it seems questions older than 10 minutes which are unanswered mostly remain unanswered. Is it then allowed to reask the question or is editing enough to bring it up or is a bount the only way to go?

I'm quite new to stackoverflow so please don't shoot me.

Comment: Generally, reposting the same question with a slightly different composition is discouraged, although you can delete the older question; you should edit the previous question. Also, there are times when you're more likely to get views, due to more user activity, but this doesn't automatically mean you'll get views, just there's more opportunity.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I remove my old question.

Comment: Now... That doesn't mean to delete an older question in favor of a new question because you didn't like the responses. This can also get you into "trouble".

Comment: Well I didn't get any responses for the question I like to delete ... probably it was not clear enough or too elaborate/specific.

Comment: See this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/168269

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is only 30 minutes old, and it's Saturday afternoon...  patience, Michel-san.

[From the FAQ:](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

> First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

It sounds like you're already going through the natural steps to improve your question.  You could issue a bounty if you wanted to bump up the profile a little more.  Realistically though, you may just want to wait until Monday and see if it gets more action when people are "working".

Comment: Yes maybe I am a little spoiled because of the smart people here :-) .... I use it for both work and 'hobby project' questions and hobby project questions (like the one from this) is at 'strange times'... Thanks for the clarification.